# Why does Eclipse IDE unlike other IDEs force using a workspace?

Tags: eclipse

Why does Eclipse IDE unlike other IDEs force using a workspace?
Even if you have just one project. What reason behind that?

Comment: This is a design decision that was made for the first release over 20 years ago, not sure anybody remembers now.

Comment: The assumption _"unlike other IDEs"_ is not true. For example, [VSCode has adopted the concept of workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces) from Eclipse too. Having a single monolithic project is a corner case and not recommended.

Comment: I don't mind to have a workspace but what to do when i don't need it? Or should I still have a workspace for one project? I really need just one project at the moment.

Comment: @ivanavdeyev Sure, you can only have one workspace containing one project. There is a checkbox to not to be asked on startup of Eclipse. When starting Eclipse with the parameter `-data <workspace>` the dialog is also not shown. In `<workspace>/.metadata` Eclipse saves preferences and caches for performance reasons and other things.